# xargs command after 'echo command'

Tags: bash, centos7

```
list_services="/nfs/backup/service1.tar.gz
/nfs/backup/service2.tar.gz
/nfs/backup/service3.tar.gz"
path_log='/var/log/'

for i in $list_services
  do
    echo "$i" >> $path_log/server1_$DATE.log | xagrs -I % echo "rm -f %" | sh
done
```

Can anybody please explain to me if this syntax "echo "$i" >> $path_log/server1_$DATE.log | xagrs -I % echo "rm -f %" | sh" is wrong. I run this script on centos7.

when i run scripts, it dont't delete any file in $list_services

Thank you so much in advanced!

Comment: Please add a suitable shebang (`#!/bin/bash`) and then paste your script at http://www.shellcheck.net/ and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: What are you trying to do? `| xargs | sh` won't do anything because there's no input

Comment: @Fravadona I'm trying to delete each file in $list_services and then write to the logfile $path_log/server1_$DATE.log to control what file is deleted. What command should I use in this situation?

Comment: @Cyrus thanks, I use #!/bin/bash for my script.

Comment: You need to use `tee` if you want output to go to a file and to STDOUT (`tee -a` to append). You shouldn't need to pipe to `sh`, `xargs` can run `rm` directly (without the `echo`)..